# Applying CSS 'blur()' filter to an image with already applied 'brightness()' filter deactivates the latter

Tags: css, css-filters

I got an image with the class that already darkens it to 50%:

```
.f_pixx {
width: 100%;
filter: brightness(50%);
-webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
-moz-filter: brightness(50%);
-o-filter: brightness(50%);
-ms-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

I also got some tiny class, which aim is just to blur:

```
.blurrme {
-webkit-filter: blur(3px);
 filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Thus, I have written a simple JS line to add this blur class to my image on hover event, however, as soon as the blur effect takes place, it immediately removes the existing brightness. I know that it is allowed to use multiple filters, so where's the trick here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(50%) blur(3px);
filter: brightness(50%) blur(3px);
```

Replacing the `class` will remove the previous property and will apply new property

So in `JS` you will need to include `brightness` also

Comment: Thanks Vitorino! Actually, my mistake was that I've tried using multiple filters by separating them with comas, that's why it never worked!